# Why can't I load files from my local machine (file:///) using SRI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, static-assert, subresource-integrity

I have some webpages I am trying to load in my browser from `file:///` and I have integrity hashes on the JS and CSS.

The JS and CSS don't load with the integrity hash present in the `<link>` and `<script>` tags but they load with it removed.

```
$ openssl dgst -sha384 -binary assets/css/bootstrap.min.css | openssl base64 -A
MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO
```

and I have the following `<script>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO">
```

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the console.

Comment: In which browsers? You observe the same behavior in all browsers — assets don’t load, no errors in the console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker good question. I was using Chrome, and it didn't work, but in FF it loaded fine. Then I exited and restarted Chrome and started getting CORS error messages in the console, so I added a `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute and the error went away, and I see the file getting loaded in the Network tab, but still no styles are being applied.

Comment: For Chrome you might want to disable all your extensions and try again

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the hash value provided for the integrity attribute is generated based on the file content. So make sure you are generating the appropriate hash from the file 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'. comprehensive explanation can be found from https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/04/understanding-subresource-integrity/